# Pytorch: Why loss functions are implemented both in nn.modules.loss and nn.functional module?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

Many loss functions in Pytorch are implemented both in nn.modules.loss and nn.functional.

For example, the two lines of the below return same results.

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.functional as F
nn.L1Loss()(x,y)
F.l1_loss(x,y)
```

Why are there two implementations?

1. Consistency for other parametric loss functions
2. Instantiation of loss function brings something good
3. otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think of it as of a partial application situation - it's useful to be able to "bundle" many of the configuration variables with the loss function object. In most cases, your loss function *has to* take `prediction` and `ground_truth` as its arguments. This makes for a fairly uniform basic API of loss functions. However, they differ in details. For instance, not every loss function has a `reduction` parameter. [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) has `weight` and `pos_weight` parameters; [`PoissonNLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.PoissonNLLLoss) has `log_input`, `eps`. It's handy to write a function like

```
def one_epoch(model, dataset, loss_fn, optimizer):
    for x, y in dataset:
        model.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

which can work with instantiated `BCEWithLogitsLoss` equally well as with `PoissonNLLLoss`. But it cannot work with their functional counterparts, because of the bookkeeping necessary. You would instead have to first create

```
loss_fn_packed = functools.partial(F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits, weight=my_weight, reduction='sum')
```

and only then you can use it with `one_epoch` defined above. But this packing is already provided with the object-oriented loss API, along with some bells and whistles (since losses subclass [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module), you can use forward and backward hooks, move stuff between cpu and gpu, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is the code of BCEWithLogistsLoss without doc:

```py
class BCEWithLogitsLoss(_Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight: Optional[Tensor] = None, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction: str = 'mean',
                 pos_weight: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> None:
        super(BCEWithLogitsLoss, self).__init__(size_average, reduce, reduction)
        self.register_buffer('weight', weight)
        self.register_buffer('pos_weight', pos_weight)

    def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
                                                  self.weight,
                                                  pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
                                                  reduction=self.reduction)
```

If parameter passing isn't considered, class and function implementation are same exactly. However, use class implementation can keep your code more concise and readable, e.g.
use function

```py
loss_func=binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
def train(model, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight):
    for x, y in dataloader:
        model.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

use class

```py
loss_func = BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
def train(model, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer):
    for x, y in dataloader:
        model.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

If you have several parameters or different loss functions, the class implementation is better.